# How would you return to the state you left the page in in an Android app?

Tags: java, android

By this I mean, I have page A, and it has the users saved username as the title (so every user has a different title when logged in in their account). When I click  the BUTTON it runs this onclick method, `Intent q = new Intent(Profile.this, Profile.class);` which I had thought it would basically just refresh the page, but instead the username is no longer there. I've tried multiple approaches but I am a beginner so I am having a lot of difficulty on what direction I go.

Comment: There is a class Bundle that is used as a variable called savedInstanceState... It is the parameter of many onCreate methods, so look after that. As an alternative, you can look out for the use of SharedPreferences... Check out the Bundle first.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to refresh page, you have to call recreate() method in butoon onclick method. Then the page will be recreated. So all fields in the page will be cleared. If you want to set the previous data in fields , then you can store them in shared preference. And set it again in all fields after refreshing.

Comment: TL:DR; `reacreate()` recreates the contents of the activity (refresh) instead of creating a new activity instance. The new instance has cleared its content because it is a new instance, even if it is the same activity class

Answer (score 1):

To referesh the Current Activity, use this on Button Click.

```
    public void onClick (View v)
    {
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
        finish();
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Comment: You create a new activity using this. When you use an intent to refresh the content, it clears the content if savedINstnaceState isn't used